# how to validate key value pair for validation without if-else

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, use-state, key-value

I am checking if the object value is empty string and if the value is empty then i am setting the state variable warning value for that same key true

```
const PrimaryEntryDetails = {
    name: "Pinak",
    number: 79777777,
    address: ""
}

const [warning,setWarning] = useState({
    name: false,
    number: false,
    address: false
})

 Object.keys(PrimaryEntryDetails).map((key) => {
     if(PrimaryEntryDetails[key] === ""){
         setWarning({...warning, [key] : !PrimaryEntryDetails[key]})
     }
  })
```

if the value of PrimaryEntryDetails key is empty then I am updating the warning state variable but it's not working properly.

Comment: Are you sure you only want to set a single warning (that's what your `if... else if` does)? Or do you want to set warning flags for every missing entry?

Answer (score 2):

I think using a list of property names is more maintainable:

```js
const propertyNames = [
  'productName',
  'productMaker',
  'model',
  'productDescription',
  'datePurchase',
  'productPrice',
];

const missingProperty = propertyNames.find(name => PrimaryEntryDetails[name] === '');

if (missingProperty) {
  setWarning({...warning, [missingProperty]: true});
}
else {
  setWarning(WarningProp);
  onContinue();
}
```

Comment: You need to know and update the names to do this - also it will only warn one element

Comment: @mplungjan Correct: That is how the example code works. OP just asked how to keep it DRY, and they already know the names.

Comment: Where does OP say they know the names already?

Comment: @mplungjan They are currently typed in the example using dot notation.

Comment: `I want to check it using the key-value pair so that i don't have to write 100 of if condition to check` reads as if OP does not want to need to know the names

Comment: @mplungjan That's not my interpretation, but OP can clarify if so. I interpret "100" as "a lot of properties" (in OP's opinion), rather than the literal value 100.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format

```
const PrimaryEntryDetails =  {
  "productName": "Name of product",
  ....
```

You could use .entries without the need to know or update a list of names

NOTE: This version will warn on ALL missing values and not just stop at the first

```js
let warnings = 0;
Object.entries(PrimaryEntryDetails).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (value.trim() === "") {
    setWarning({ ...warning,
      [key]: true
    })
    warnings++;
  }
})
if (warnings === 0) { // assuming the code in your example worked
  setWarning(WarningProp);
  onContinue();
}
```

If you want to warn on the first empty one, use find

```js
let warnings = 0;
const entry = Object.entries(PrimaryEntryDetails).find(([key, value]) => value.trim() === "")
if (entry) setWarning({ ...warning, [entry[[0]]: true })
else {
  setWarning(WarningProp);
  onContinue();
}
```